# Whose record did the Chicago Bulls team of 1995-96 break?

Tags: basketball, history, nba, records

The Chicago Bulls broke the NBA record for most victories in a season during the 1995-96 season. The question is, whose record did they break?

Answer (score 12):

[Chicago Bulls](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi8kvPy0tjLAhXMVo4KHaP3CWkQFggnMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nba.com%2Fbulls%2F&usg=AFQjCNGw9fKT91pva_Zs9VoFblfPTVc3CQ&sig2=AYt33ag5ZowymG1uNUwspw) held the record for most wins in a single NBA season with 72 wins in the [1995-96 season](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwipw4Os09jLAhWIj44KHaDxBTUQFgg5MAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nba.com%2Fhistory%2Fseason%2F19951996.html&usg=AFQjCNEytJj1jCrkzmbQFTePktCx3XjaPQ&sig2=UPV3n9Db4RTQSMVxsm655Q), which has since been surpassed by the 2015-2016 Golden State Warriors (with 73 wins).

Prior to that, the record for most number of wins in a single NBA season was held by the [Los Angeles Lakers](http://www.nba.com/lakers/) team for the [1971-72 season](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjD4KTU09jLAhUCVY4KHZG-A5sQFgg4MAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nba.com%2Fhistory%2Fseasonreviews%2F1971-72%2F&usg=AFQjCNEAc1S0U8WjyhqtjNktVHTuBlRpLw&sig2=nJ8vSXwlUo0M0fgqtsO-mQ) with 69 wins. Conincidentally, the Bulls recorded 69 wins in the [1996-97 season](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjShJei1NjLAhVCaxQKHfN1BWoQFgg0MAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nba.com%2Fhistory%2Fseasonreviews%2F1996-97%2F&usg=AFQjCNECnkBa7jWE2nP1Jf8RbGQlGg9cXw&sig2=TseffREVDdjhuWTNqaaf_A) as well.

The top 10 list for total number of wins in a season can be found [here](https://www.basketball-reference.com/leaders/team_wins.html).